# How can I force a secure websocket connection with vapor swift?

Tags: swift, websocket, vapor

I have a websocket server set up with vapor swift. Now I want to force the connection to use the `websocket secure` protocol from the server side. It's not enough to use a URL like `wss://url:8080` because then the client controlls wheter the connection is secure or not.

```
webSocketServer.get("link") { (socket, request) in
    // check if the connection is secure?
    // or force a secure connection?
}
```

How is it possible to force vapor to use the secure version of websocket?

Or better, how could I check if the connection is secure?

Comment: I guess it'd be better to use nginx for it